# Magento2: the text "%1 successfully updated" appears after some of the prices on the category page?

Tags: magento2

[image]

On the category page, after some variable prices (ab means from in german), this weird text appears.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use phpstorm you can search for it in your entire project to see where it is currently being called.